# a wrong output precision in numpy

Tags: python, ipython, precision

Given the script below

```py
import numpy as np
xx = np.arange(-.5,4.5,0.1)
yy = np.arange(-.5,4.5,0.1)
XX,YY = np.meshgrid(xx,yy)
np.hstack(XX)[10]
```

The output is `0.4999999999999998`,  but the expected output is `0.5`. I have tried `%precision 1`, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: This isn't an issue, [this is how floating-point math works](https://0.30000000000000004.com)

Comment: Floating point values cannot exactly represent a lot of decimal values; such as 0.1. See the link provided in @ForceBru's comment. Floating point numbers are "inexact". There are packages for representing exact arbitrary decimal values. See, for example, `pydoc decimal`. I have no idea if Numpy supports any of those types.